# Why mongoose middleware "pre" remove with { query: true } is not called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm a bit stuck on this problem. 
I have read all the mongoose documentation about middleware and some stackoverflow issue and was unable to find-out how to solve my problem without duplicating queries (find then remove).

Normally, pre middleware on remove will not fire when call from Model and not from document. But according with [the doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#naming), if I add {query: true}, my function will be called from model query.

I use the latest monngoose version (5.4.16)

Here is my code.

```
let mySchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  comment: String
}, { usePushEach: true });

mySchema.pre('remove', { document: true }, function() {
  console.log('remove document');
});
mySchema.pre('remove', { query: true }, function() {
  console.log('remove');
});
const MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', mySchema);
```

And the call here

```
MyModel.deleteOne({ _id: modelId }, (errorRm) => {
  if (errorRm) {
    return res.json({ success: false, message: `${errorRm.message}` });
  }
    return res.json({ success: true, message: 'Model successfully removed' });
  });
```

The model is successfully removed but nothing is logged from the "pre" functions...

Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using **MyModel.deleteOne()**. Use **MyModel.remove()** and it will work.

Acoording to the documentation:

> You can pass options to Schema.pre() and Schema.post() to switch whether Mongoose calls your remove() hook for Document.remove() or Model.remove():

Comment: I was using Model.remove() before and that was not working either... but that was before upgrading mongoose(4.13.4 to 5.4.16). You are right that works, I juste update all my call this morning... thanks for the help

Comment: `.remove()` has been deprecated since version 5.3